# What could cause a virtual machine to start on its own?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a server with VMware ESXi 6.5 and a couple virtual machines.
There's one VM in particular that starts when I power on another VM (always the same). They are both Windows 7 VMs with VMware tools installed. I don't use the autostart feature.

What could cause a VM to start when another one is powered on? Is this a bug? I can't understand.

Comment: Is the host managed by a vCenter server or not? Any other VMware or third party products, or scripts in use that could cause this behavior? What is shown in "Tasks" and "Events" when the second VM powers on?

Comment: Using a desktop virtualisation software ? like view or xendesktop, as they can controlthe power on too

Comment: It's a very simple setup : One ESXi 6.5 host, a few virtual machines, and nothing else (I have the free license so there's no vCenter). The two virtual machines are not on the same vSwitch so it can't be WoL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's [VMware Orchestrated Restart](https://featurewalkthrough.vmware.com/#!/vsphere-6-5/orchestrated-restart/) feature. Check VM configuration.